# Is there any way to use flow to restrict specific string patterns?

Tags: reactjs, flowtype

I'm using Flow on a React webapp and I'm currently facing a use-case where I'm asking for the user to input certain time values in a "HH:mm" format. Is there any way to describe what pattern is being followed by the strings?

I've been looking around for a solution but the general consensus which I agree to to a certain point seems to be that you don't need to handle this kind of thing using Flow, favouring using validating functions and relying on the UI code to supply the code following the correct pattern. Still, I was wondering if there is any way to achieve this in order to make the code as descriptive as possible.

Comment: It's possible to do if you want to create a union type of all possible strings but there isn't a good way to type a generic pattern in Flow. For example, you could do `type ValidInput = '00:00' | '00:01' | '00:02' | ... | '24:59'` but you couldn't do `type ValidInput = <regex pattern>`.

Comment: A union type of all the possible string possibilities is definitely not feasible in this kind of situation...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to create a validator function, but enhanced using Opaque Type Aliases: https://flow.org/en/docs/types/opaque-types/

Or, more specifically, Opaque Type Aliases with Subtyping Constraints: https://flow.org/en/docs/types/opaque-types/#toc-subtyping-constraints

You should write a validator function in the same file where you define the opaque type. It will accept the primitive type as an argument and return a value typed as the opaque type with subtyping constraint.

Now, in a different file, you can type some variables as the opaque type, for example in function arguments. Flow will enforce that you only pass values that go through your validator function, but these could be used just as if they were the primitive type.

Example:

`exports.js`:

```
export opaque type ID: string = string;


function validateID(x: string): ID | void {
    if ( /* some validity check passes */ ) {
        return x;
    }

    return undefined;
}
```

`import.js`:

```
import type {ID} from './exports';

function formatID(x: ID): string {
    return "ID: " + x; // Ok! IDs are strings.
}

function toID(x: string): ID {
    return x; // Error: strings are not IDs.
}
```