# Make flow assume that a particular key does exist in a Map

Tags: flowtype

Due to the way you're iterating over something, you may know that a key always exists in a Map but flow may not know.

Currently, how I'm getting rid of it is to check if the result returned from `get()` is not undefined.

I don't want to add those spurious checks though, and instead I want to tell the typesystem that it can assume that that key exists. Telling this to the typesystem also conveys more information (this key definitely exists) about the program to a future reader than a spurious check (this key may or may not exist, and if doesn't exist then we're ignoring that case)

So I want to be able to do the following by preferably adding something on or before line 3 instead of an if check.

```
1. let score:Map<string, number> = new Map()
2. initialize(score); // some magic initilization of the map that flow doesn't understand
3. score.get("hello");
```

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't recommend doing this but you could `extend` the `Map` class to define your own class that defines `get`,

```
declare class MyMap<K, V> extends Map<K,V> {
    get(key: 'hello'): V;
    get(key: K): V | void;
}
```

so that `(new myMap()).get('hello')` has type `V` instead of `V | void`. For example,

```
const myMap: MyMap<string, number> = new MyMap();
const n: number = myMap.get('hello');
const o: number = myMap.get('not hello'); // error
const p: number | void = myMap.get('not hello');
```

[Try Flow](https://flow.org/try/#0CYUwxgNghgTiAEkoGdnwLIE91QA4B4BpAGngDUA+eEADwBcQA7YNHAky+AbwCh5-4AcxB0AFAFtMAZVzgAllAiEQmAFzwA5AAsQECAHsNASnVkA3HwHCxAaxXrCJ8vAA+8AG765wCwF8ePGD6jMh08JJs6lhs+KEwcoyCpIwAruIARiAwVAC88IwgAO4Y2HiiRhZBIWGM6qkZWfB5EXgAdNai2roGxpXBofD6dWmZME3hpbjtIp2M+mE6eoYV8AD0q9QwMPowgf1huMMNY26e3uMtUx0acwvdy2ZAA)

You'll need to change your code so that `initialize` returns a `MyMap` instead of modifying the passed in `Map`. Note that although this will pass Flow, it may still break during running. As you can see in the example above, even though I have created a `new MyMap()`, I have not added the key `'hello'` and so `n` isn't really a `number`.

Comment: This seems like it wouldn't scale. I.e. If I wanted to access the whole range of keys "hello1" to "hello1000" which initialization function has set.

Comment: Yeah, unfortunately there's no good way to have a union of lots of strings in Flow. Would be cool if you could use regex in a type but I don't think there are any plans of that nature. You might be able to do something like what's mentioned in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55909030/is-there-any-way-to-use-flow-to-restrict-specific-string-patterns so that the first signature becomes `get(key: MySpecialKey): V;` where `MySpecialKey` is an `opaque` type.